# Is there a primary responsibility a service class should have?

Tags: java, service, soa

There are several Java source class files in our codebase (written in past) that has "service" in their name. All the methods in these service classes are static and some are like utility methods.

My question is - What kind of primary responsibility a service class should have? Is there a set of rules on should keep into consideration while designing a service?

Comment: What is **your** definition of service ? It's not clear what you are asking and what is inside those services,can you add examples?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, service layer is responsible for keep business logic and talking to DAO layer. Its vary abstract and if you try to divide you app into just controller, service and dao, you will end up putting in lot of code under service layer.

I prefer to define service class as an entry point to my biz logic. That is controller can call only and only service layer. We try to avoid adding static methods to service layer. 
Say I have a user service, it will expose methods related to users. Behind service layer we have dao, utilities dto entities etc. Also service class or anything below it can call other service classes.